Problems with serial connection on Wemos-S2 mini board using the Arduino rosserial library
I'm kinda new to both ROS and asking for solutions in forums, as usually there has always been someone with my same problem who got a solution before me, so please be patient if i'm not thorough enough with my description ;)
My problem can be described as follows:
when I upload a simple sketch using rosserial (both in Arduino IDE and Platformio) the code gets uploaded with no errors, but as it gets to 100% the board suddenly disappears as a serial device.
As possible solutions, I did the following:
changed the ros.h file in order to use hardware serial instead of tcp this way
#if defined(ROSSERIAL_ARDUINO_TCP)// (deleted the ESP32 and ESP8266 definitions)
  #include "ArduinoTcpHardware.h"
#else
  #include "ArduinoHardware.h"
#endif

and, as suggested here,
I added the following code to the ArduinoHardware.h file:
#define SERIAL_CLASS HardwareSerial
  #if defined(USE_USBCDC)
    // ESP32-S2 ESP32-C3
    #define SERIAL_CLASS USBCDC
  #elif defined(USE_HWCDC)
    // ESP32-S3
    #define SERIAL_CLASS HWCDC
  #else
    #define SERIAL_CLASS HardwareSerial
  #endif

with this second solution, i get the following error:
cannot convert 'USBCDC*' to 'HardwareSerial*' in assignment

can someone please help me understand how to solve this issue?
the code i was trying to upload is the one in this example.

As it turns out, the problem was my sleep schedule.
after a good nap, i returned to my code and noticed the following:
I had forgotten to define USB_CDC in my main code (this way it works even without using the -DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=0 flag)
due to my scarce knowledge of GitHub I didn't notice that I wasn't supposed to copy and paste the whole highlighted part of ArduinoHardware.h, but I had to remove the red part from my library and add the green part (I know, duh).
now everything seems to work just fine, thanks everyone for the help, turns out i just neededed to sleep on it :)

for Wemos-S2 mini board, you can use micro ros in esp-idf. It is a bit of a learning curve and I don't consider this as a direct solution to your problem but an alternative that will work out of the box with the examples available in the git repository.
--- To resolve the issue, you can add the
-DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=0
option to your platformio.ini file under platformio_options. Here is the configuration:
---
platformio_options:
  board_build.extra_flags:
     -DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=0

I have the same board and this configuration worked for me. It compiled and ran successfully. --- –

this will be a module for a ROS1-based rover, and as such it won't support any version of micro ros, so I'm stuck with rosserial


To resolve the issue, you can add the -DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=0 option to your platformio.ini file under platformio_options. Here is the configuration:
platformio_options:
  board_build.extra_flags:
    - "-DARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=0"

I have the same board and this configuration worked for me. It compiled and ran successfully.


Please [edit] and put your solution in your answer, so that all of the info is in one place. Code is rather difficult to read in comments as formatting and line breaks aren't visible. In addition, comments are ephemeral in nature and tend to get deleted over time. Thanks.
